# Receiving account and 417 errors when attempting to test Apple Pay via braintree-web-drop-in package

Tags: javascript, braintree, applepay

Currently using [braintree-web-drop-in](https://www.npmjs.com/package/braintree-web-drop-in) for payments in my React web app.  Currently have both Paypal and Credit Card payments working fine, but I'm having trouble getting ApplePay to go through.

I am doing my testing using a sandbox Braintree account, and a sandbox Apple Tester account.  I've followed the [Braintree guide](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/apple-pay/configuration) to setting up Apple pay, and I've also followed the [Apple Pay Sandbox guide](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/).  Here's the code I have for the Braintree Dropin rendering:

```
getApplePayRequestObject() {
  const total = this.total;

  return {
    total: {
      label: 'Testing 123',
      amount: total,
    },
    countryCode: 'US',
    currencyCode: 'USD',
  };
}

createPaymentForm() {
  const paypalConfig = config.payPalEnabled && { paypal: { flow: 'vault' } };
  const applePayConfig = config.applePayEnabled && {
    applePay: {
      displayName: 'My App',
      paymentRequest: this.getApplePayRequestObject(),
    },
  };

  dropin.create(
    {
      authorization: this.props.token,
      selector: '#braintree-container',
      paymentOptionPriority: ['card', 'paypal', 'applePay'],
      ...paypalConfig,
      ...applePayConfig,
      card: {
        overrides: {
          styles: {
            input: {
              padding: '0 8px',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    (err, instance) => {
      if (instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
        this.setState({ formLoaded: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ braintreeError: strings.paymentCantBeProcessed });
        console.error(err || 'Payment form instance could not be initialized');
      }
    }
  );
}
```

With this I have the Apple Pay button rendering successfully in safari.  As I said, Both Paypal and Credit Card payments in this sandbox Braintree account are working perfectly fine.

[image: braintree-web-drop-in apple pay rendering success]

I'm having two issues at the moment with Apple Pay.  When I first select Apple Pay, I get the following error:

```
Could not find an active card. This may be because you're using a production iCloud
account in a sandbox Apple Pay Session. Log in to a Sandbox iCloud account to test 
this flow, and add a card to your wallet. For additional assistance, visit 
https://help.braintreepayments.com
```

This doesn't make sense, as I specifically created a Sandbox Tester Account through the apple developer console, and when I logged in/added cards to the account on my Mac, it even said "Sandbox" at the top of the dialog.

Second, if I try to proceed with payment, I receive a `417 Expectation Failed` error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Payment Services Exception merchantId={id1 here} unauthorized to process transactions on behalf of merchantId={id2 here} reason={id2 here} is not a registered merchant in WWDR and isn't properly authorized via Mass Enablement, either"
    },
    "fieldErrors": []
}
```

Googling this error has provided me no insights into the problem, or possible solutions.

How do I resolve these errors and successfully complete a payment via Apple Pay using `braintree-web-drop-in`.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I work at PayPal. If you have any further questions,  [contact support](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/help).

417's are almost always issues with [domain registration](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/apple-pay/configuration#domain-registration). Double and triple check the following:

1. You must have [an apple developer account](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/)
2. You have to be logged into an [iTunes Connect sandbox tester account](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/) on your browser (you can create a sandbox tester account by following the steps listed in [Apple's sandbox testing guide](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/)

It sound like you have these two covered, but I'm laying them out anyway just to be extra sure.

When adding your domain to the Control Panel, it **has to be a fully qualified domain name**. Things to double check about the file hosted at the URL you provide:

1. The file hosted has to be hosted at the correct location
2. The URL you supply is publicly available (no intranet, no firewall, no bot blocking). Apple has to be able to programmatically check that this file is downloadable at the URL you provided.
3. The URL supplied is HTTPS. HTTP will not be accepted.

When in doubt, you should be able to publicly access the URL you supply on any device and see a page that looks very similar to [this](https://readwritetools.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association). If you're not seeing that there's an issue with the domain you registered.